# Add row if not exists, or retrieve its id for other query

Tags: mysql

This questions mixes several questions already answered, but I can't put all the answers together to make it work.

I have three tables :

Table **`users`** :

`| user_id | user_name |`

Table **`events`** :

`| event_id | event_date | event_name |`

Table **`user_event`** :

`| user_id | event_id |`

Table **`user_event`** is a child from the previous tables and associate a user to an event (foreign keys defined to its parent table, with `ON DELETE CASCADE`).

Each user can add an event, but if the event already exists, it won't create a duplicate in the table **`events`**, but will still insert a row in **`user_event`** with the `user_id` and the **existing** `event_id` of the event already saved.

The code I have to only add an event if it doesn't exist already :

```
INSERT INTO `events` (`event_id`, `event_date`, `event_name`) 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'event_1', '2014-05-20',  'Meeting') AS tmp 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT `event_id`, `event_date`, `event_name` 
    FROM `events` 
    WHERE `event_name` = 'Meeting' 
    AND `event_date` = '2014-05-20') 
LIMIT 1;
```

Then I want to save it into user_event table so that I know that this user is going to this event :

```
INSERT INTO `user_event` (`user_id`, `event_id`) VALUES ('user_1', 'event_1');
```

If it is a new event, it is all fine as I know the event ID in advance but if another user is creating an already existing event :

`user_2` creates the following event (same as previously inserted, but different id) :

```
`event_name` = 'Meeting'
`event_date` = '2014-05-20'
`event_id` = 'event_2'
```

I want to insert in the table `user_event` the following entry :

```
| user_2 | event_1 |
```

Maybe it is possible to combine those queries into one and user sql variables, or maybe by defining `id = last_insert_id(id)` and retrieving it through php before submitting the second query, but can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The event_id column is auto increment right?

If you put this at the end of your insert query, it will give you a last_insert_id() value for php, even if there is a duplicate value in events. Then you can use that to insert into user events.

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE event_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(event_id)
```

You must make a unique key in the mysql table for the unique column (event_name) for this to work.

Comment: Thank you, my ids are not auto-increment. I might consider putting them as such. How would you use `event_id = last_insert_id()` afterwards for the second query ?